# Debian: Add start up script to bootable USB

Tags: debian, scripting, startup

So I've installed [WANem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) and the only way to download it is by downloading a WANem custom version of Knoppix OS with WANem already installed. I want to add a start up script to configure something every time I start this OS, but since there's no option for me to install the OS and I have to run it from USB every time, I see no way to do this.

**Is there a way for me to add a start up script to a bootable USB?**

Comment: I thought the `/etc/rc*.d` system was used for boot scripts, `knoppix` is `debian` based after all. [Supposedly](https://community.gns3.com/docs/DOC-1170) you can run `WANem` in `GNS3` or `VMWare` which doesn't help your question but may help simplify usage/setup.

Comment: It is. But since I'm loading the OS off of a USB, any time I create a file it is erased on shutdown.

Comment: I'd ask on the `WANem` [forums](http://sourceforge.net/p/wanem/discussion/) as I wouldn't expect that behaviour if installed